# SQL Server stored procedure join table ON T1.ID=mid(T2.valutation)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have T1 with parts of the car, like this:

```
ID  Name
-------------
1   Tyres
2   Gearbox
3   Engine
4   Body
5   Brakes
6   ..
```

and T2 with the list of the cars with a column called `valutation` that contains a string of numbers [0-9]

```
ID  Brand   Model   Color   Year    KKm     ....    valutation
---------------------------------------------------------------
1   Audi    A3      Green   2014    185             86354
```

Each number in `valutation` refers to a part of the car according to its position in the string: ie

```
8, since it is in position 1, refers to Tyres
6, since it is in position 2, refers to GearBox
...
4, since it is in position 5, refers to Brakes
```

and so on

I need to build a SQL Server stored procedure that return this

```
ID  Brand   Model   Color   Year    KKm     Tyres   GearBox   Engine   Body   Brakes
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Audi    A3      Green   2014    185       8         6       3        5       4
```

I tried some solution but as you can see from the (wrong) subject of the question I actually do not really know which kind of function is required.

Thanks

Comment: This is a very poor design.  You should really rethink it instead of building a proc to work around it.

Comment: Your database design is badly flawed. The fact you're having to do this should be a very clear indication of that to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL to do that.  I haven't got access to SQL server so cannot check this but I would just do:

```
declare @sql varchar(200)
declare @i int

set @sql = 'select *'
set @i = 1

While @i <= (select count(*) from T1)
begin
  set @sql = @sql + ', substring(valuation,' + cast(@i as varchar(10)) + ',1) as ' + (select name from T1 where id = @i)
  set @i = @i + 1
end

set @sql = @sql + ' from T2'

exec(@sql)
```

(I've copied your apparent misspelling of 'valuation', i.e., I've assumed it's spelt 'valutation' in your table.)

Comment: would be great, but I think you cannot use a select for the alias :-(

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake in my code.  Now corrected to move the select statement outside of the quotes and also move the @i outside.  Wasn't thinking clearly.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes, with some minor changes now it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

AS @dfundako pointed out, this is very poor design and will likely haunt you down the road.

However, as with most programming, "anything is possible".

So here's a quick version of what you want, using a CTE.

This is not a dynamic version, in the sense I am hard-coding your labels from the lookup table.  You can take it from here:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id int, Valuation VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @t
    SELECT ID, Valuation FROM T2
;WITH cte AS
    (SELECT id, Valuation, SUBSTRING(Valuation, 1, 1) AS position_char, 1 AS ind FROM @t
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT id, Valuation, SUBSTRING(Valuation, ind + 1, 1) AS position_char, ind + 1 FROM cte WHERE LEN(Valuation) > ind
    )

SELECT T2.Model, T2.Brand, T2.Color, T2.valuation,
     p.[1] AS 'Tyres', [2] AS 'Gearbox', [3] AS 'Engine', [4] AS 'Body', [5] AS 'Brakes'
FROM cte 
PIVOT (MAX(position_char) 
    FOR ind IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) p
INNER JOIN T1
    ON p.id = T1.ID
INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

[image: Output]

The proper relational structure you want, if you can change it, is more like the following:

[image: Proper Structure]

Comment: Yes I know this is the probably the worst way to approach the problem, but since it is absolutely not the core table of the db.. this was much easier to handle because T1 is not static: now has some 12 records but could rise to more than 40. I used the string for that reason but perhaps it is better if I rebuild everything in different way.